# Show/hide div based on checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user checks 'student'(check-1). The 2 checkbox values are supposed to disappear and reveal a text input div. As of right now I've got the input-reveal down. But I can't seem to get the checkboxes to disappear.

I've tried:

```
$(function () {
  $('#check-1').change(function () {                
      $('.name').toggle(this.checked);
      $('#check-1').hide();
      $('#check-2').hide();
  }).change();
});
```

But that doesn't work. How do I hide the checkboxes once 'student' is checked? Any idea's?

Here is a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkAy4/8/) . Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Why do you hide *both*?

Comment: You're hiding the checkboxes, but not the labels. (Is this what you're asking?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your textboxes with a div, say "thisWrapper"

```
<div id="thisWrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" class="checkchoice staff" required><label for="check-1" class="choice staff">Staff</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-2" class="checkchoice student" required><label for="check-2" class="choice student">Student</label>
</div>
```

and in the change event you posted add:

```
  $("thisWrapper").hide();
```

that should hide both checkboxes at once.  Of course you'll have to add a "cancel" or "Reset" button to show the checkboxes again.

or you could give the checkboxes both a new class name  like "mycheckboxes" and call this:

```
$(".mycheckboxes").click(function() {
        $('#check-1').hide();
$("#check-2").hide();
});
```

*** HERE"S THE FULL EXAMPLE I GOT WORKING IN FIDDLER ****

Try this instead:

```
<div id="thisWrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" class="checkchoice" required><label for="check-1" class="choice staff">Staff</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-2" class="checkchoice" required><label for="check-2" class="choice student">Student</label>
</div>
<div id="nameinput">
    <input type="text" placeholder="So what's your name?" />
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {

       $(".checkchoice").change(function() {
              $("#thisWrapper").hide();
               $("#nameinput").show();
       });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion. But it seems that everything just disappears.

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought you wanted to hide the labels.  Try this instead:
$("#check-2").click(function() {
      $('#check-1').hide();
      $('#check-2').hide();
}

Comment: look at my code above - working in fiddler if you copy and paste it - sorry i dont' use fiddler much lol

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. Am I missing something [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vkAy4/15/) .. (forgot the reveal)

Answer (score 4):

See the code below:

```
$(".my-check").change(function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $(".my-box").show();
    } else {
        $(".my-box").hide();
    }
});
```

More details in:
http://jsfiddle.net/marloscarmo/vMFQd/